# C - Print Specific Line From Text File

Tags: c, file, search

I'm new to programming so please be nice.

Currently I'm trying to write a program that opens a text file, reads in two words, searches through the text file counts how many times the two words appear, and then finally prints the first line that the first word appeared on.

So far this is what I have done:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

FILE *infile;
char inputWord1[100], inputWord2[100], filename[100], wordInText[100], line[500]; 
int i, count, strComp, word1Count, word2Count, wordLen, lineCount; 
char c;

int main() { 
    printf("Enter the first word: "); 
    gets(inputWord1); 
    printf("Enter the second word: "); 
    gets(inputWord2); 
    printf("Enter the file name: "); 
    gets(filename); 

    infile = fopen(filename, "r"); 
    if(infile == NULL) { 
        printf("Error"); 
        exit(1); 
    } 

    word1Count = 0; word2Count = 0; lineCount = 1;
    while(fscanf(infile, "%s", wordInText) != EOF) { 
        wordLen = strlen(wordInText);
        for(i = 0; i < wordLen; i++) {
            if(wordInText[i] >= 65 && wordInText[i] <= 90) { 
                wordInText[i] = wordInText[i] + 32; 
            }
        }

        for(c = getc(infile); c != EOF; c = getc(infile)) {
            if(c == '\n') { 
                lineCount = lineCount + 1;
            }
        }

        strComp = strcmp(wordInText, inputWord1); 
        if(strComp == 0) { 
            word1Count++;
            if(word1Count == 1) { 
                for(int x = lineCount; x <= lineCount; x++) {
                    fgets(line, 500, infile); 
                    printf("%s\n", line);
                }
            }
        }
        strComp = strcmp(wordInText, inputWord2); 
        if(strComp == 0) { 
            word2Count++; 
        }
    }
    printf("Word 1 appears %d times\n", word1Count); 
    printf("Word 2 appears %d times\n", word2Count);
}
```

So all this works except:

```
strComp = strcmp(wordInText, inputWord1); 
        if(strComp == 0) { 
            word1Count++;
            if(word1Count == 1) { 
                for(int x = lineCount; x <= lineCount; x++) {
                    fgets(line, 500, infile); 
                    printf("%s\n", line);
                }
            }
        }
```

The last for loop isn't working properly. It prints out the \n but does not print the line. I really don't know why it's not working. All the other parts work fine.

If anyone has any ideas on how to resolve this I would really appreciate it. Please keep in mind I only know basic C functions and I haven't completely finished this program (still need to convert entered words to lowercase).

Comment: Are you sure you want `for(int x = lineCount; x <= lineCount; x++)`?

Comment: You need to scan your file line by line. Duplicate the first line. Then display number of  words and finally dump the duplicate line.

Comment: `gets()` is bad, use `fgets()` slways. :-)

Comment: @Ôrel could you please explain in a little more detail? 

SouravGhosh I did use `fgets()` to retrieve the lines and then I used `gets` to get strings not related to the file. 

Thank you the help guys

Comment: well, that's not true. see `gets(inputWord1);`.

Comment: Omitting all other problems, when you loop to count lines, you consume all chars of file. Then when you `fgets(line, 500, infile);` you are already at the end of file.

Comment: @LPs Thank you!!! This really helped me fix it! I read about the `rewind` function to go back to the top of the file and have managed to fix it that problem. My program isn't fully finshed yet but this has really helped me a lot! Thanks. I'll update this once I'm done later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gets should be replaced to avoid buffer overflow
I have used some define, when we find the word the input line is dup and print at the end.
File is read line by line, each line is split word by word.
Parsing should be updated, allows several spaces for example, support more word separator etc...

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                             
#include <string.h>                                                            
#include <stdlib.h>                                                            
#include <ctype.h>                                                             

#define WORD_LEN_MAX 100                                                       
#define LINE_LEN_MAX 500                                                       

int main() {                                                                   
    FILE *infile;                                                              
    char inputWord1[WORD_LEN_MAX], inputWord2[WORD_LEN_MAX];                   
    char filename[WORD_LEN_MAX];                                               
    char wordInText[WORD_LEN_MAX], line[LINE_LEN_MAX];                         
    char firsAppear[LINE_LEN_MAX];                                             
    int word1Count, word2Count, lineCount, i;                                  
    printf("Enter the first word: ");                                          
    gets(inputWord1);                                                          
    printf("Enter the second word: ");                                         
    gets(inputWord2);                                                          
    printf("Enter the file name: ");                                           
    gets(filename);                                                            


    infile = fopen(filename, "r");                                             
    if(infile == NULL) {                                                       
        printf("Error cannot open %s", filename);                              
        exit(1);                                                               
    }                                                                          

    word1Count = 0; word2Count = 0; lineCount = 1;                             
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), infile) != NULL) {                         
        char *p = line;                                                        
        lineCount++;                                                           
        while (*p != '\0' && *p != '\n') {                                     
            i = 0;                                                             
            while (*p != ' ' && *p != '\0' && *p != '\n') {                    
                wordInText[i++] = tolower(*p++);                               
            }                                                                  
            if (*p == ' ') {                                                   
                p++;                                                           
            }                                                                  
            wordInText[i] = '\0';                                              

            if(!strcmp(wordInText, inputWord1)) {                              
                word1Count++;                                                  
                if(word1Count == 1) {                                          
                    strncpy(firsAppear, line, sizeof(firsAppear));             

                }                                                              
            }                                                                  
            if(!strcmp(wordInText, inputWord2)) {                              
                word2Count++;                                                  
            }                                                                  
        }                                                                      
    }                                                                          
    printf("Word 1 appears %d times\n", word1Count);                           
    printf("Word 2 appears %d times\n", word2Count);                           
    printf("%s", firsAppear);                                                  
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. This is exactly what I needed, appreciate it a lot! :)

Comment: Just a quick question if you don't mind: 
Why do you use `#define WORD_LEN_MAX 100` and then `arrayName[WORD_LEN_MAX 100]` instead of `arrayName[100]`? Just curious because I have never been taught this. Is there any advantage to  defining the max size over just writing in the max size of the array? Thanks again.

Comment: With this solution, if you want to change the size you need to upadte only one line, and it adds some information of what it 100 or 500

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. However, the approach you have chosen has to be toward the more difficult end of the spectrum. When looking for the correct tools to use, when reading **lines**, using **line-oriented** input is almost always the proper choice. That being so, `gets` is **never** the proper choice. It is horribly insecure and has been dropped from the C library, use `fgets` instead (or `getline`).

Avoid the use of **global variables**. The have no use in your program. There are limited uses for them, but for simple programs, you will almost never use them.

When you need to compare words and sum the number of matches, just do that... Compare and if they match increment the sum. Nothing else is required.

As for the `lineCount` if you use **line-oriented** input, it's trivial, just increment the counter for each line read.

But how to get the words to test? `strtok` (or `strsep`) are the tools provided. Just read a line and **tokenize** it. Then just compare and increment.

I put together a short example. (most of the code is just stripping the `newline` from the end of the input). It is simple, read a line, tokenize, compare and increment on match, increment the lineCount. Done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Avoid Globals */

#define MAXL 500
#define MAXW 100

int main (void)
{
    char inputWord1[MAXW] = { 0 };      /* Always Initialize your Variables */
    char inputWord2[MAXW] = { 0 };
    char filename[MAXW] = { 0 };
    char line[MAXL] = { 0 };
    char *token = NULL;
    char *delim = " ,.;\n";
    size_t word1Count = 0;              /* can't be negative, use   */
    size_t word2Count = 0;              /* size_t or unsigned       */
    size_t lineCount = 0;
    size_t len = 0;
    FILE *infile = NULL;

    printf ("\nEnter the first word: ");        /* Do NOT use gets, it is insecure  */
    fgets (inputWord1, MAXW, stdin);            /* use fgets or getline instead     */        

    len = strlen (inputWord1);
    while (len > 0 && (inputWord1[len-1] == '\n' || inputWord1[len-1] == '\r'))
        inputWord1[--len] = 0;                  /* strip newline or carriage return */

    printf ("\nEnter the second word: ");
    fgets (inputWord2, MAXW, stdin);

    len = strlen (inputWord2);
    while (len > 0 && (inputWord2[len-1] == '\n' || inputWord2[len-1] == '\r'))
        inputWord2[--len] = 0;                  /* strip newline or carriage return */

    printf ("\nEnter the file name: ");
    fgets (filename, MAXW, stdin);

    len = strlen (filename);
    while (len > 0 && (filename[len-1] == '\n' || filename[len-1] == '\r'))
        filename[--len] = 0;                    /* strip newline or carriage return */

    infile = fopen (filename, "r");
    if (infile == NULL) {
        printf ("error: file open failed. '%s'\n", filename);
        exit (1);
    }

    printf ("\nThe lines processed are:\n\n");

    /* read each line, tokenize, compare and increment */
    while (fgets (line, MAXL, infile) != NULL)
    {
        len = strlen (line);
        while (len > 0 && (line[len-1] == '\n' || line[len-1] == '\r'))
            line[--len] = 0;                    /* strip newline or carriage return */

        printf ("  %2zu  %s\n", lineCount, line);
        for (token = strtok (line, delim); token != NULL; token = strtok (NULL, delim)) 
        {
            if (strcmp (token, inputWord1) == 0)
                word1Count++;
            if (strcmp (token, inputWord2) == 0)
                word2Count++;
        }

        lineCount++;
    }

    printf ("\nWord 1 appears %zu times\n", word1Count);
    printf ("Word 2 appears %zu times\n", word2Count);
    printf ("Number of lines: %zu\n\n", lineCount);

    return 0;
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/countw1w2

Enter the first word: me

Enter the second word: chequer

Enter the file name: dat/ll_replace_poem.txt

The lines processed are:

   0  Eye have a spelling chequer,
   1  It came with my Pea Sea.
   2  It plane lee marks four my revue,
   3  Miss Steaks I can knot sea.
   4  Eye strike the quays and type a whirred,
   5  And weight four it two say,
   6  Weather eye am write oar wrong,
   7  It tells me straight aweigh.
   8  Eye ran this poem threw it,
   9  Your shore real glad two no.
  10  Its vary polished in its weigh.
  11  My chequer tolled me sew.
  12  A chequer is a bless thing,
  13  It freeze yew lodes of thyme.
  14  It helps me right all stiles of righting,
  15  And aides me when eye rime.
  16  Each frays come posed up on my screen,
  17  Eye trussed too bee a joule.
  18  The chequer pours over every word,
  19  Two cheque sum spelling rule.

Word 1 appears 4 times
Word 2 appears 4 times
Number of lines: 20
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me really appreciate you taking your time to do that. I learnt a lot from your post very help! I would upvote if I could (lack enough reputation).

Comment: Not a problem, just happy to help. There are many ways to approach solving most problems in C. This is probably the standard way of doing it, but there is absolutely nothing wrong with the way you approached it. Good luck with your code.